# Automatically generate a delete post link and provide it to post creator

Tags: custom-post-types

My web site shows posts created from not logged in users. They submit to a custom post type with the plugin Contact Form 7 and Post My Contact Form 7. But the posts are kind of an offer, so they can expire. Therefore, I need post delete links. As the users are not logged in, I need to provide the delete link as soon as the user submits his post.

I thought of using `get_delete_post_link()`, but I have no clue how to get the correct link to the correct post and where to implement this. Maybe using an event listener? I am so lost..

Comment: the first step is to create a unique and secret key when the post is created to be sure that nobody else can delete the post. then you can use `admin-ajax.php` to create the link : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins and the link looks like `...wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=delete_post&id=1234&secret_key=ADF498FR5465SZER`

Comment: If you provide a link to delete those posts, and logged out users can use it, then anybody can delete any post. `get_delete_post_link()` is going to give a link to the Admin area which will require a login to access. You'll also need a mechanism to prevent users just seeing the delete link, then repeatedly calling it with different values. This is going to be extremely difficult to secure without reinventing logging in somehow

Comment: @Kaperto I would not recommend the ancient admin AJAX API, the REST API is both easier to learn and easier to debug for making AJAX requests ( there's nothing special about the REST API, it's just a much nicer interface to make AJAX requests to )

Comment: Hi Tom, Well I thought of providing the delete post link just to the person who just submitted the form. Something like: As soon as he presses on the submit button I will prompt him with the delete link for his post, so he can copy paste it and keep it "safe". So I don't want the users to have to log in and I don't show the delete link publicly. Also I don't really care if the delete post link can be modified, so someone can delete every post he would like. I have a very specific "audience", I don't think that would be a problem.

Comment: @TomJNowell  the REST API returns JSON content, here Cracmeister need to redirect to a page after the deletion of the post.

Comment: @Kaperto the REST API can return XML and HTML etc, in this case I would expect a JSON response telling you if the deletion was succesful. Even then, if you're making a JS AJAX request then the JS can make a redirect afterwards easily, I fail to see how there is any difference between the Admin AJAX and REST APIs here, especially since they both have the same result. If you're advising that the browser goes straight to Admin AJAX where the AJAX endpoint itself does the redirection, then I would consider that misuse and bad practice. Admin AJAX is not a form handler

Comment: @TomJNowell maybe my first comment was not clear. the link I put in example is the link that delete the post and then it need to send a redirect header after that. since the start, it's not a good practice to modify data when going on a link then it's not easy to answer this question and both using good practices.

Comment: That's not true, if doing it via PHP you can handle it via a nonce and a URL parameter, if you're doing it via JS you make a REST API call then either redirect or display an error depending on the outcome.

Comment: @Cracmeister note that since we don't know why you're doing this or the context, the ability to answer the question is heavily compromised. Any context would be super helpful, it's difficult to reason about things when they're deliberatly generic

Answer (score 0):

> I thought of using get_delete_post_link(), but I have no clue how to get the correct link to the correct post and where to implement this. Maybe using an event listener? I am so lost..

Either passing in the post ID, or making sure you're inside a post loop would work, but since you mentioned this is for logged out users, this function is a non-starter because it will send users to WP Admin.

So instead, you have 2 options:

1. Force users to be logged in, and set that user as the author
2. Save a unique identifier in the post data then pass it back along with the post ID and a nonce. Then you can make a request containing all 3 items to verify it is indeed the author deleting the post

**Warning:** Without some form of verification, anybody will be able to delete anything on your site just by running through every possible post ID. This is trivial to do.

How you might implement that request can take 2 forms:

1. Send the user to the same page, and put URL parameters with the post ID and verification values. Then in `functions.php` look for those values, verify the user can do that, delete the post via `wp_delete_post`, then redirect onwards
2. In JS, when the user clicks the delete link/button, make an authenticated REST API request to delete the post, passing along the post ID and any needed information. If it's succesful, redirect the user. If it's not succesful, display a message

If the user is logged in, the verification data part can be skipped. If you insist on logged out users, then you'll need a custom REST API endpoint for option 2.

#### Contact Form 7

This is the more difficult part, how you might save a verification key to the post CF7 creates, or pass that into the response CF7 gives, is not something this site can cover. For this part you will need to contact CF7 support avenues, be that official support, communities, meetup groups, FB groups, etc